# How to disable "Chrome for Testing is only for automated testing. For regular browsing, use a standard version of Chrome that updates automatically"?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-devtools, chrome-for-testing

I am using Chrome For Testing (CFT) browser for Selenium WebDriver with Java. I feel the info message "Chrome for Testing is only for automated testing. For regular browsing, use a standard version of Chrome that updates automatically" is redundant for me and want to disable this.

I was looking for any option [here](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) but could not find.

Please help.

Comment: Try adding `--test-type=gpu` command line switch.

Answer (score 0):

As of [this commit](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/5012709) (Nov 2023), the `--disable-infobars` switch has been introduced.

Thus, with a recent version of CfT, just run:

```
google-chrome --disable-infobars
```